# Testing Java class

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am testing Java app with JUnit. The following is the source code of a specific method:

```
public class Surgery {
    Vector<Patient> patients;
    String name;

    public Surgery(String name) {
        patients = new Vector<Patient>();
        this.name = name;
    } 

     public Patient findPatient(String name) {
         Iterator<Patient> patientIt = patients.iterator();
         while(patientIt.hasNext()) {
             Patient next = patientIt.next();
             if (next.getName().equals(name))
                return next;
         }
         return null;
     }
```

This is JUnit test method:

```
public class SurgeryTest {
    private Vector<Patient> vector;
    Surgery surgery_N =new Surgery("Teddy");
    ByteArrayOutputStream ans = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    @Test
    public void testFindPatient() {
        surgery_N.findPatient("Teddy");
    }
}
```

I need to test each statement in the source code method. I stuck, don't know what else to do. Any solution?

Comment: this looks like a class assignment.  if so please tag this post as homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Surgery` class contains no way to add patients to it from the code sample you have given us, so your unit test should be finding nothing.

To test each statement in the source code method you should create multiple tests that cover each one of the possible paths in your code. That means, in your tests you will want to test for the scenario where you return a patient name if it exists, and one for where the patient doesn't exist (returning null).

Here's some example methods for you to work from:

```
public void testFindPatientWherePatientExists() {
    Patient thePatient = surgery.findPatient("Teddy");
    assertEquals("Teddy", thePatient.getName());
}

public void testFindPatientWherePatientDoesntExist() {
    assertNull(surgery.findPatient("I dont exist"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected result when you call `findPatient(...)`? You can compare the *expected* result with the *actual* result using `assertEqual(...)`

```
public class SurgeryTest {
    Surgery surgery;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         surgery = new Surgery("Teddy");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindPatient() {
        Patient p = ...;  // expected result
        assertEquals(p, surgery.findPatient("Teddy"));
    }
}
```

The method with `@Before` annotation will be called before each method with `@Test` annotation. Therefore, the new surgery object is tested every time.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the name you pass to the Surgery constructor does NOT get placed into the patients Vector.  It is a field of Surgery.  Suggest you rename the arg to "surgeryName" and then you'll need a new method, addPatient(String patientName);, and call addPatient("Teddy").

That said, in general, you should test for both the name present and name absent case.  e.g.

(exact name of the assert methods might vary)

```
assertNotNull(surgery.findPatient("Teddy"));
assertNull(surgery.findPatient("A Name I did not add"));
```

(first line would be more precise if it were assertEquals() like wannik suggested.